# What is my mistake in configure port based virtualhost in Apache server?

Tags: apache

I tried to configure port no based virtual host in APACHE server, i am getting below error

```
[root@ram conf]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ram
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully  qualified            domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Wed Oct 14 15:11:37 2015] [warn] VirtualHost 192.168.2.3:80 overlaps    with VirtualHost 192.168.2.3:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
 [Wed Oct 14 15:11:37 2015] [warn] NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.3:2233 has no VirtualHosts
 (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:2233
 (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:2233
  no listening sockets available, shutting down
  Unable to open logs
                                                       [FAILED]
```

[root@ram conf]# 
In this case my configuration file is

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.3:80>
ServerAdmin root@lopcalhost
DocumentRoot "/opt/sample"
DirectoryIndex "welcome.html"
ServerName "host.admin.com"
```

```
  Listen 2233           
  NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.3:2233
  <VirtualHost 192.168.2.3:80>
  ServerAdmin root@lopcalhost   
  DocumentRoot "/opt/web1"
  DirectoryIndex "123.html"
  ServerName "host1.admin.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. Are you sure this is not what you meant, or intended?

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.3:2233>
ServerAdmin root@lopcalhost
DocumentRoot "/opt/sample"
DirectoryIndex "welcome.html"
ServerName "host.admin.com"

  Listen 2233           
  NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.3:2233
  <VirtualHost 192.168.2.3:2233>
  ServerAdmin root@lopcalhost   
  DocumentRoot "/opt/web1"
  DirectoryIndex "123.html"
  ServerName "host1.admin.com"
```

How are you accessing these sites? Is this a development server on a LAN, that is not your dev machine? Or a LAN server that only the LAN accesses?

Also, try commenting out this line:

```
# NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.3:2233
```

then restart apache server and see if that corrects it. Do you want apache to be listening only to port 2233 or to port 2233 and port 80?

if both, you want, I think:

```
Listen 2233
Listen 80
```

ADDED, based on comments:
Try this then:

```
Listen 2233  
Listen 80        
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost 192.168.2.3:80>
ServerAdmin root@lopcalhost
DocumentRoot "/opt/sample"
DirectoryIndex "welcome.html"
ServerName "host.admin.com"
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.2.3:2233>
ServerAdmin root@lopcalhost   
DocumentRoot "/opt/web1"
DirectoryIndex "123.html"
ServerName "host1.admin.com"
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Does that work?

Why are you not using 127.0.01 for the local machine? The only time you need the static machine IP is if you are accessing the sites from outside your dev server, ie, a machine elsewhere in your network, or outside it, assuming port forwarding etc in the router.

By the way, I realized it's also possible you are simply unaware that you can use your local machine etc/hosts file to send requests based on the site name.

You didn't say what operating system you are using, in OSX and Unix/Linux, it's /etc/hosts (not positive about osx since I never use it, but I assume that's the same)

https://superuser.com/questions/525688/whats-the-windows-equivalent-of-etc-hosts
Sample windows path: if it's missing, just create the hosts file there and save it (I don't use windows so I don't know if this has changed).
\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc

Sample using /etc/hosts and 127.0.0.1:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost site1 site2
```

Then sample apache config:

ADDED, based on further comments:
With /etc/hosts:

```
Listen 80        
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerAdmin root@lopcalhost
DocumentRoot "/opt/sample"
DirectoryIndex "welcome.html"
ServerName "site2"
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerAdmin root@lopcalhost   
DocumentRoot "/opt/web1"
DirectoryIndex "123.html"
ServerName "site1"
...
</VirtualHost>
```

This will work and create two sites that can be accessed separately, in your browser, like: http://site1/ http://site2/

Comment: I just want to access local machine only .Its showing  error when i comment

 "NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.3:2233"

Comment: i just want to to configure two  sites on different ports . i want to configure welcome.html in :80  and 123.html in :2233 port no .
                           @ Lizardx

Comment: I am using linux redhat . me also wrote same what you post ? i just did not post Listen 80 , why because that was default that was defined in httpd.conf file . i got same error

Comment: that's fine, I tried. My feeling/suspicion is that you are not saying a critical piece of information, or you are not clear on what your actual use case is for, but it's too hard to guess, on a well setup system, without any further glitches or unusual requirements, what I posted works.